# Fragment disappearing when coming back from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a viewpager with 3 fragments to make a swipeable widget. When I first load the app they show properly and all the click events work as expected. Same with hitting the back button after clicking each OnClick, sends me back to landingpagenotlogged in and the viewpager/fragments are displayed as expected. My problem is when I hit my menu button and come back to the landing page my view pager disappears.

I did try to use `getChildFragmentManager()` when setting the adapter and it works but then my onClick events do not work any more as I get no view to id *******.

I have also tried to place the adapter in the `onResume();` with no luck at all.

Along with the viewpager,  my viewpagerindicator is not working for the homewidget but working for the carousel. Not sure if that is the code or the layout. But I set it up the same way as the carousel and still not seeing it within the screen when run.

**Landingpagenotlogged**

```
public class LandingPageFragmentLoggedOut extends LandingPageFragment {

    private static final String TAG = LandingPageFragmentLoggedOut.class.getSimpleName();
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private RelativeLayout myStoreTab;
    private Button signIn;
    private final static Fragment instance = new LandingPageFragmentLoggedOut();
    LoggedOutWidgetAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    public static final int ITEMS = 3;


    static public Fragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                WeeklyAdService.class));

        setShoppingListFocusChangeListener();
        setSignInBtnClickListener();
        super.setViewPagerMotionListeners(viewPager);
        setMenuTouchListener();
        setTabClickListener();
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    protected void inflateFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landingpage_not_logged_in, container,
                false);

        RelativeLayout thisLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.landingpage_logged_out_parent_layout);
        TileBackground.fixBackgroundRepeat(thisLayout);
        imgArch = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_tab);

    }

    private void setSignInBtnClickListener() {
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.enter_in_from_bottom, R.anim.anim_static);

                params.put("Module", "Home");
                FlurryAgent.logEvent(FlurryConstants.GOTO_SIGN_IN, params);
            }
        });
    }


    private void setTabClickListener() {
        myStoreTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tabSelection = 1;
                tabSelectionListener.onTabSelectionListener(tabSelection);
                toggleStoreTabIndicator(1);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    protected void setUIreferences() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.home_carousel);
        overlay = view.findViewById(R.id.landingpage_screenOverlay);
        indicator = (LinePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.image_slider_indicator);
        this.signIn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.landingpg_sign_in_btn);
        shoppingListBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icnlistoptions);
        myStoreTab = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_tab);
        menuButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.imgBanner_list);
        logoButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerLogo);
        addShoppingListItemWidget = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editAddItemNotLoggedIn);
        addShoppingListItemWidget.setOnKeyListener(null);
        addedItemConfirmation = view.findViewById(R.id.addedItemConfirmation);
        imgScanner = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgScannerNotLoggedIn);
        toggleScannerVisibility(true);
        itemAddedText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_added_text);
        weeklyAdImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.weeklyad_img);
        defaultWelcomeMsg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.landing_page_default_img);
        setWeeklyAdThumbNail();
        if(imgUrl!=null)
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl).transform(new MyTransformTop()).error(R.drawable.img_ad_default).into(weeklyAdImg);
        else
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.img_ad_default).into(weeklyAdImg);
        //setWeeklyAdOnClickListener();
        setWeeklyAdClickListener();
        couponsGrid = view.findViewById(R.id.coupons_grid);
        couponsPlaceholderImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feat_coupons);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            itemAddedText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        }


        imgScanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PermissionHandler.openCamera(getActivity());
            }
        });

        mShoppingListAdd = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.shoppinglis_shortcut);
        mShoppingListAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAdapter = new LoggedOutWidgetAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpHomePageWidget);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        LinePageIndicator mLoggedOutWidgetIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.homewidgetLoggedOutIndicator);
        mLoggedOutWidgetIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }

    // MSM - 214
    private void setWeeklyAdThumbNail() {
        try {
            if (LocalDb.getStoreId() != LocalDb.DEFAULT_VAL) {
                if (weeklyAdBundle != null && !weeklyAdBundle.isEmpty()) {

                    //MSM - 155
                    if (!Utils.isStringNull(weeklyAdBundle.getString("WeeklyAdThumbnail"))) {
                        Log.e("BANNER ID SET: ", weeklyAdBundle.getString("WeeklyAdThumbnail"));
                        imgUrl = weeklyAdBundle.getString("WeeklyAdThumbnail");
                    }
                    else
                        imgUrl = weeklyAdBundle.getString("0FirstThumbnail");
                }
            }

            if (urls == null || !urls.contains(imgUrl)) {
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl).transform(new MyTransformTop()).error(R.drawable.img_ad_default).into(weeklyAdImg);
            }
            else
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.img_ad_default).into(weeklyAdImg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void sendRequest() {
        if (CheckNetworkConnection.isConnectionAvailable(activity)) {
            jsonParser = new CarouselJSONParser(this);
            jsonParser.execute();
        } else {
            setDefaultOfflineImage();
            weeklyAdImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_ad_default);

            // TODO Set OFFLINE message here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setCarouselData(ArrayList<CarouselImageData> imageDatas) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Set Carousel Data hit");
        if (imageDatas != null) {
            this.advertisements = imageDatas;
            runnable(advertisements.size());
            handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEW_PAGER_DELAY);
            viewPager
                    .setAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapter(activity, imageDatas, this, weeklyAdBundle));
            indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


            if (isFirstTimeLaunched) {
                fadeInWelcomMsg();
                Log.v(TAG, "first time launched, welcome message initaited");

            } else {
                viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.v(TAG, "Returning user, viewpager set visible");

            }
        } else {
            setDefaultOfflineImage();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (LocalDb.isLoggedIn()) {
            Fragment fragment = new LandingPageFragment();
            launchNavigationItemFragment(fragment);
        }

        getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                WeeklyAdService.class));
        if (viewPager == null) {
            viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.home_carousel);
        }
        mAdapter = new LoggedOutWidgetAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        super.onResume();

        if (newItemIsAdded) {
            onShoppingListResult();
        }
    //    addShoppingListItemWidget.clearFocus();

    }

    @Override
    void runnable(final int size) {
        handler = new Handler();
        animateViewPager = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!pageIsSliding) {
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == size - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(
                                viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEW_PAGER_DELAY);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    void toggleStoreTabIndicator(int tab) {
        if (storeTabIsClosed) {
            storeTabIsClosed = false;
            imgArch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_single_arch_my_store);
        } else {
            storeTabIsClosed = true;
            imgArch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_arch);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void setFontsOnTextViews(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void setTabClickListeners() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPagerMotionListeners(ViewPager vPager) {

    }

    public class LoggedOutWidgetAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public LoggedOutWidgetAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment.init(position);

                case 1:
                    return ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment.init(position);

                case 2:
                    return MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment.init(position);

                default:
                    return null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }
    }
}
```

The three fragments that are tied to the viewpager

**ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment**

```
public class ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment extends Fragment {
int fragVal;
int storeId;
String storeName, storeLat, storeLong, retail_store_id;
TextView mProductLocatorClickZone;
StoreList sList;

public static ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment init(int val) {
    ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment productLocatorFragment = new ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("prodLocator", val);
    productLocatorFragment.setArguments(args);
    return productLocatorFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("prodLocator") : 1;
    sList = new StoreList();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_locator_search_widget, container, false);

    mProductLocatorClickZone = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.editSearchItemNotLoggedIn);

    mProductLocatorClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sList = LandingPageFragment.storeList;
            if(sList.getId() != null){
                storeId = Integer.parseInt(sList.getId());
                storeLat = sList.getLatitude();
                storeLong = sList.getLongitude();
                storeName = sList.getName();

                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductSearchActivity.class);
                FlurryTrackerHelper.onProductLocatorWidget();
                mIntent.putExtra("store_id", String.valueOf(storeId));
                mIntent.putExtra("store_lat", storeLat);
                mIntent.putExtra("store_lng", storeLong);
                mIntent.putExtra("retail_id", retail_store_id);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
            else if (sList.getId() == null) {
                if (LocalDb.getStoreId() > 0) {
                    storeId = LocalDb.getStoreId();
                    storeLat = LocalDb.getStoreLat();
                    storeLong = LocalDb.getStoreLng();
                    storeName = LocalDb.getMyStoreName();
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductSearchActivity.class);
                    FlurryTrackerHelper.onProductLocatorWidget();
                    mIntent.putExtra("store_id", String.valueOf(storeId));
                    mIntent.putExtra("store_lat", storeLat);
                    mIntent.putExtra("store_lng", storeLong);
                    mIntent.putExtra("retail_id", retail_store_id);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            }
            else {
                StoreLocatorDetailsSearchFragment storeLocatorDetailsSearchFragment = new StoreLocatorDetailsSearchFragment();
                Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
                b1.putInt("currentFragment", 10);
                storeLocatorDetailsSearchFragment.setArguments(b1);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_item_fragment_container, storeLocatorDetailsSearchFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
    return layoutView;
}
}
```

**MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment**

```
public class MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    EditText mShoppingListClickZone;
    ImageView mShoppinglistScanClickZone;

    public static MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment init(int val) {
        MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment myShoppingListFragment = new MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("myShoppingList", val);
        myShoppingListFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myShoppingListFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("myShoppingList") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_widget, container, false);
        mShoppingListClickZone = (EditText) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.editAddItemNotLoggedIn);
        mShoppingListClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShoppingListItemsFragment shoppingListItemsFragment = new ShoppingListItemsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_item_fragment_container, shoppingListItemsFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        mShoppinglistScanClickZone = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.imgScannerNotLoggedIn);
        mShoppinglistScanClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PermissionHandler.openCamera(getActivity());
            }
        });
        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

**ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment**

```
public class ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    LinearLayout mCouponSearchClickZone, mRefillPrescriptionClickZone;
    View mDivider;

    public static ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment init(int val) {
        ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment productScanFragment = new ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("prodScan", val);
        productScanFragment.setArguments(args);
        return productScanFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("prodScan") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_scan_widget, container, false);
        mRefillPrescriptionClickZone = (LinearLayout) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.refillPrescriptionClickZone);
        mCouponSearchClickZone = (LinearLayout) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.couponSearchClickZone);
        mCouponSearchClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ECouponsViewFragment eCouponsViewFragment = new ECouponsViewFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_item_fragment_container, eCouponsViewFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        if (LocalDb.getBannerSupportRefillPrescriptions().equalsIgnoreCase(
                UtilConstants.KEY_WORD_FALSE)) {
            mDivider = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
            mDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRefillPrescriptionClickZone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            mRefillPrescriptionClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AddPharmacyFragment addPharmacyFragment = new AddPharmacyFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_item_fragment_container, addPharmacyFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }
        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and not the FragmentPagerAdapter.

So I removed the old FragmentPagerAdapter in LadingPageLoggedOut and replaced it with

```
inal String [] fragmentClasses = {"com.supervalu.mobile.android.HomeScreenWidget.ProductLocatorHomeWidgetFragment",
            "com.supervalu.mobile.android.HomeScreenWidget.ProductScanHomeWidgetFragment",
            "com.supervalu.mobile.android.HomeScreenWidget.MyShoppingListHomeWidgetFragment"};
    mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpHomePageWidget);
    mPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragmentAtPosition = null;


            // Check to make sure that your array is not null, size is greater than 0 ,
            // current position is greater than equal to 0, and position is less than length
            if((fragmentClasses != null) && (fragmentClasses.length > 0)&&(position >= 0)&& (position < fragmentClasses.length))
            {
                // Instantiate the Fragment at the current position of the Adapter
                fragmentAtPosition = Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), fragmentClasses[position]);
                fragmentAtPosition.setRetainInstance(true);

            }

            return fragmentAtPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentClasses.length;
        }
    });
```